# Negative Values in RED in Datatables

Tags: jquery, html, css, salesforce, datatables

Now i have succesfully implemented the datatables on my VF page. i have one last requirement : i need to show any negative values in red and in bold in any of the numerical columns. As my implementation is in salesforce i am using  for my table. Each of the  having numerical values has some id. the following is what i am trying to implement in javascript -

```
$('#JustTable PriorEP').each(function()
{ 
var valu = $(this).val();
alert(valu);
if(valu < '0')
   {
        $('#JustTable PriorEP').css('color', 'red');
   }
```

});
Table id = "JustTable", column id ="PriorEP"
.Its not working.

KK, now i changed the code to

```
          $('#JustTable PriorEP').each(function()
        {   
         var valu = $(this).val();

      if(parseInt(valu) < 0)
      {
          alert(parseInt(valu));
          $(this).css('color', 'red');
      }

  });
```

The alert is not thrown up even once

Comment: do you have more than one id with same name? "PriorEP", can i have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Try this  $('#PriorEP').css('color', 'red');

Comment: you should parse the value as integer or float using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`. and use `$(this).css('color','red')`

Comment: simply using #PriorEp is not working, i get the alert but only once it should come for as many records are there in column with "priorEP"

Comment: PriorEp is the id for the column, so all tds in each row will have PriorEp as their id...hence i am using each() function...i have implemented the parseint idea..still not working

Comment: edited the question...still no solution

Comment: Try one of these solutions from datatables forum: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6106/conditionally-set-column-text-color/p1

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle: Nah, used this http://datatables.net/ref#fnCreatedCell

Comment: @MrLister you are right, am removing my comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hehe, solved it using datatables API itslef. Scrapped the jquery and changed my datatable initilization as following:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
"aoColumnDefs": [ {
  "aTargets": [4,5,6,7,8,9],
  "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
     if ( sData < "0" ) {
                      $(nTd).css('color', 'red')
                      $(nTd).css('font-weight', 'bold')
    }
  }
} ]
});
} );
```

Here, aTargets lets you specify which column numbers to apply function to.
fnCreatedCell is the function that lets you define what should happen when a certain type of data is found, in  my scenario, Bold and red if value less than 0